# tipaman and tasks packages don't goes together

Tags: lists, enumerate, multicol, enumitem, tasks

I would like to use the `tipaman` package with `tasks` but it's seems they don't goes together. What can I do in this case since I'm looking for left to right alignment of the individual items?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipaman}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}[style=enumerate](5)
\task Man   {\Huge  \textipa{/\ae/}}
\task Heart {\Huge  \textipa{/\textinvscripta :/}}
\task Box \textipa{/\textopeno/}} 
\task Luck  {\Huge \textipa{/\textturnv/} }
\task friend  {\Huge \textipa{/e/} } 
\task cat  {\Huge  \textipa{/\ae/}}  
\task admit  {\Huge \textipa{/i/} }
\task Man   {\Huge  \textipa{/\ae/}}
\task Heart {\Huge  \textipa{/\textinvscripta :/}}
\task Box \textipa{/\textopeno/}} 
\task Luck  {\Huge \textipa{/\textturnv/} }
\task friend  {\Huge \textipa{/e/} } 
\task cat  {\Huge  \textipa{/\ae/}}  
\task admit  {\Huge \textipa{/i/} }
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

It's produces 
[image]

but i want them to looks like

[image]

Comment: I't not entirely clear what the problem is. Do you want an output like the example image? Your MWE did not compile for me but with a few minor corrections I got a similar, correctly aligned appearance.

Comment: Yes with one condition when i add numbering i want them be left to right alignment of the individual item please

Comment: `tasks` doesn't use `\item` but `\task`. Also, I get ``! LaTeX Error: File `tipaman.sty' not found.`` with your MWE

Comment: Oh, so you're actually meaning the packages *do* go together but you don't know how to get enumerated lists with `tasks`? Then your question as it is phrased now is *quite* misleading

Comment: @Educ maybe you can try to improve the question yourself, with the help of the comments (including your own comments, which were also helpful for my understanding) and the answer? Also, when making a MWE, try to pay attention to the M for minimal (which you did) as wel as the W for Working (which you didn't do) by using the right packages (`tipa` instead of `tipaman`) and the right syntax (`\task`, and for example the extra closing bracket for _Box_). That way, we can focus on the actual problem (the use of `enumerate` in this context) instead of solving syntax issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following MWE generates a list similar to the example image. It is numbered left to right (using `\enumerate` as task style) and aligned in columns. Note that the elements of the `tasks` environment are denoted with `\task`. The phonetic alphabet packages used are `tipa` (basic symbols) and `tipx` (extended symbols, in this case `\textinvscripta`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}[style=enumerate](4)
\task Man\\{\Huge \textipa{/\ae/}}
\task Heart\\{\Huge \textipa{/\textinvscripta :/}}
\task Box\\{\Huge \textipa{/\textopeno/}} 
\task Luck\\{\Huge \textipa{/\textturnv/} }
\task friend\\{\Huge \textipa{/e/} } 
\task cat\\{\Huge \textipa{/\ae/}}  
\task admit\\{\Huge \textipa{/i/} }
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]